# Best practice: Use of stdint types in a header file

Tags: c, header, stdint

What's the best way to ensure that `stdint.h` is included for headers that use the types from that header?

The alternatives I can see are:

- including `stdint.h` in the header itself (dangerous, is it not?)
- flagging something to the compiler if it's not included when parsing the header (something like `#ifndef _STDINT_H` with an accompanying `#error "stdint.h not included"`
- Educating the other developer in always including `stdint.h` before any of my headers that require it, either using comments, conversation, documentation or a mixture of all three (the last one being preferable).

If there are any other alternatives worth mentioning, feel free to do so - I'm just guessing at what I should do here.

Comment: Why would it be dangerous to include `stdint.h` in the header?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't actually know the answer to that question - I was just told once that including headers in headers is dangerous, but wasn't given any further explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use types from `stdint.h` in your header, you really *should* include `stdint.h` in that header.

It is generally preferred to include the least amount of files from a header to reduce compile time. Therefore, whenever possible, you should forward declare types in headers. Since the types from `stdint.h` cannot be forward declared (they're just typedefs of primitive types), there is no other option than including `stdint.h` in the header.

Answer (score 0):

I my oppinion, including header files in header files is ok if you use include guards.

Something like

```
# ifndef HEADER
     # define HEADER
     # include header.h
# endif
```